# React error: "error 'AbortController' is not defined "

Tags: reactjs, controller

I built a mini-website with react - everything was working fine until I logged on today. Now I cannot render it and instead get the following error: "AbortController' is not defined".

Part of the code is:

```
const useFetch = (url) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const abordCont = new AbortController();

        setTimeout(() => {
            fetch(url, { signal: abordCont.signal })
            .then(res => {
                if(!res.ok) {
                    throw Error('could not fetch data for that recource');
                }
                return res.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                setIsPending(false);
                setData(data);
                setError(null);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                if (err.name === 'AbortError') {
                    console.log('fetch aboarded');
                } else {
                    setIsPending(false);
                    setError(err.message);
                }
            })
        }, 1000);

        return () => abordCont.abort();
    }, [url])

    return {error, isPending, data};
}
```

I already tried upgrading node, it is in the newest version already (v17.9.0) and going back to version 16, but nothing helped. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the error?

Answer (score 0):

Node is used only to run webpack or other (package builder) that complies react code to static bundle with index.html, styles.css and index.js. It also runs the development server which is not included in the final builder. The react code, unless its a server side app will be executed on users computer, therefore whenever you want to access global functions should try and get them from the window object.

you should try
 `const controler = new window.AbortController()`

although a simple new react starter on stackbllitz lets you run the AbortController() directly, https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ggksv4?file=src%2FApp.tsx therfore it must be something tied to your current bundler setup.